# General questions about DAC

Tags: dac

A DAC converts a digital signal into an analog one. I looked through a lot of datasheets and most of them don't mention a output bandwidth or rise, fall time.

Can someone please explain why this values are not mentioned? I mean the DAC has most of the time a buffer to output the signal. The buffer is an opamp, every opamp has a gain bandwidth product, thats why it should mention the output bandwidth and the rise/fall time of the signal?

Comment: Take this part as example ... https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac121s101.pdf ... In the Features ... first page ... 8-µs Output Settling Time (Typical).

Comment: @Antonio51 this would indirectly explain the rise/fall time. But where is the bandwidth?

Comment: Right for the bandwith. But bandwith, I think, is related to slew-rate as it is related for the opamps. It is the same behavior. this will obviously depend on the shape of the signal that we want to build with the DAC. See my answer ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/577088/op-amp-speed-bandwidth-vs-slew-rate/577093#577093

Comment: For an MDAC (Multiplying DAC) you'll find bandwidth between the Vref pin and output. Otherwise, bandwidth is pretty meaningless; settling time and max sample rate cover that base more effectively.

Comment: With DACs we don't really talk about bandwidth, instead there will be a highest conversion rate (samples/second, for example: 1 Ms/s) or a conversion time (1 us meaning up to 1 Million samples per second = 1 Ms/s).

Comment: Example of serial DAC121S101. Fclk max = 30 MHz ... Sample rate = 30e6 / 12 (bits) = 2.5 Msps. Setting time 8-12 us ??? So I can't use the maximum speed ? But just 80 kHz ? Or use Slew-rate = 1V/us ?

Comment: @Antonio51 That 30 MHz is **only** the maximum speed of the **serial interface**. That only tells us how fast the data can be send to the IC. It does not tell us how long a proper DA conversion takes (up to 8 or 12 us). So you might be correct, it is probably possible (I am too lazy to do the calculation) to feed the sample data faster to the IC than the output can settle. But think if you have **one** serial bus and **10** of these DACs connected to that bus and each getting its own data sample. Then you might need that 30 MHz to keep all 10 DACs fully occupied.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie  - Right. Here I made the "test" for only one DAC :-) ... But this does not change the higher "frequency" you can get at one DAC output ... Speed of interface can't be correlated with "bandwith" or higher analog "frequency" at the output of the DAC. But "SlewRate" or "settling time" can  give it, unless I am wrong.

Comment: The term "*bandwidth*" suggests an amplitude tolerance of -3dB (0.7071). That's a very wide range perhaps suitable for a 3 or 4 bit-wide DAC. For more precise DACs, settling time is a more stringent spec, related to bit-precision.

Comment: Please indicate which DAC data sheets typically DO NOT show the information you are trying to find @Yoomo

Answer (score 1):

The DAC update frequency rate will be specified if parallel or implied if serial input.

e.g. fmax=30 MHz 12 bit = 2.5 MHz update rate and with a LPF order of -6dB per order slope, the signal BW will be typically <=1/3 of 2.5MHz depending on the desired characteristics.